# C# How to update data in datagridview

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, wpf, datagridview

I am building a C# wpf SQL server application and before I start there are few things that i want to ask.

1. First of, the application will be used by several clients to write data into one SQL table. In the main window of the application I will have a datagridview that will display the main table. Since data is going to be entered by more than one person, can I dynamically update the datagrid view or should I use a timer and update in once every few minutes?
2. Is it better if I open one global SQL connection and keep it open while the application is running (and if it is how can I do that) or should I create a new connection each time I want to do something?

These are the questions for now, I am sure I will have much more questions in the progress, since I am new to wpf and database programming. Thanks for the understanding :).

Comment: Update on a timer, and create a new Connection object for each contact with the SQL server.

Comment: Update: IF you were to insist on updating automatically, use a timer. But think long and hard about @Fragment 's advice not to update automatically at all.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to build your wpf application in mvvm architecture.

1. As for me, I think you should not use timers for this purpose. Because if your client will use different filters or sortings, to find custom data rows, these sudden data updates will change displayed data order, which is an unpredictable behavior (breaks UI development principles) and it will annoy everyone. The better solution, is when users will refresh data only when they need it (manually, button click), or on navigating to dataGrid table control himself (automatically).

If a client takes a record on editing, you can store record State parameter in database, and check its state to avoid collisions (editing of the same data in the same time by multiple users).

2. You should not keep the connection alive explicitly, when you're not make operation with dataBase. Since you're using WPF - the best, easy to configure and managing approach - to install EntityFramework nuget package to your project, and use Code first. 
   [Here is a good tutorials](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/entity-framework-code-first.aspx), about how to use it.

Working with your database through project models is much more reliable and simple in realization, than working through SqlConnection classes.